# Imagemagick Convert png to jxr

Tags: image, imagemagick, converters

I am facing some problem by convert and compress a *.png file to a *.jxr file.

I can't find any options like rate or quality that will change the resulting .jxr files size, in the imagemagick convert tool, does anybody now anything to manipulate the converted files size?

Comment: Have you tried something like `convert input.png -quality 80 -format JXR output.jxr`?

Comment: Already tried, but i have found the solution i will answer in some minutes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagemagick doesn't support JXR only if:

```
"Requires the jxrlib delegate library. Put the JxrDecApp and JxrEncApp applications in your execution path."
```

If you have managed to install [libjxr0](https://packages.debian.org/de/sid/libjxr0) and the [libjxr-tools](https://packages.debian.org/de/sid/libjxr-tools) linux packages, you will face the next problem, if you don't know how the two apps [JxrEncApp](http://jxrlib.codeplex.com/) and [JxrDecApp](http://jxrlib.codeplex.com/) are executed.

So here is the needed background:

- Supports only `BMP`,`TIF` and `HDR`
- Errors are not displayed only!!!!! the whole man page
- Quality parameter starts at `0.000` and ends at `1.000`

A call looks like this:

```
JxrEncApp -i test.tif -o test.jxr -q 0.231
```

Comment: I am having trouble with JxrEncApp. I have both libjxr0 and libjxr-tools installed and when I try and run `JxrEncApp -i wizard.hdr -o wizard.jxr -q 10` it replies with the man page and an empty (0 bytes) `wizard.jxr` file. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. My `wizard.hdr` file was created with `convert wizard.png -type truecolor wizard.jxr`, which should produce the requested a 24bpp RGBE image. Also, According to the man page, the latest version requires the `-q` param to be 1-10

Comment: @NickSchild Have you tried using a lower quality parameter like 5 or so?