# How to decode this binary image file if none of image processing python libraries (Pillow and cv2) are unable to read?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am trying to read this file using Pillow and cv2 in python. However, both libraries are failing to do so.

File is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EDmuOUOYxdrd-ayDQiPkI--1D32gXofs/view?usp=sharing) on google drive.

Pillow raises an "OSError: cannot identify image file 0.jpg"
cv2 returns None

This binary file has the extension ".jpg" and can be easily viewed using Window`s Photos viewer.

[image]

However, I want to read and decode this binary file as an image in python.

Any idea?

Comment: If you look at the properties of the file, does it confirm that the format actually is jpeg?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file is actually a JXR file, you can see the first few bytes are:

```
49 49 BC
```

if you load it into a hex editor like http://hexed.it

The signature is IANA registered, see [here](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000524.shtml).

---

You can read it with [imagecodecs](https://pypi.org/project/imagecodecs/) like this:

```
import imagecodecs
from pathlib import Path

# Slurp entire image data as binary
jxr = Path('0.jpg').read_bytes()

# Make into Numpy array
na = imagecodecs.jpegxr_decode(jxr)

print(na.shape)        # prints (256, 512, 3)
```

---

Alternatively, you can convert JXR to something less Microsofty with **ImageMagick** in your Terminal with:

```
magick input.jxr output.jpg
```

Or, if you have old v6 **ImageMagick**, use:

```
convert input.jxr output.jpg
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I am getting the following error:
'"JXRDecApp.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
magick.exe: delegate failed `cmd.exe /c (move "%i" "%i.jxr" >nul) & ("JXRDecApp.exe" -i "%i.jxr" -o "%o.pnm") & (move "%i.jxr" "%i" >nul) & (move "%o.pnm" "%o" >nul)' @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1913.
magick.exe: unable to open module file 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.1.0-Q16-HDRI\modules\coders\IM_MOD_RL_JXR_.dll': No such file or directory @ warning/module.c/GetMagickModulePath/675.

Comment: I don't use JXR myself so I'll have to refer you another answer on JXR support https://stackoverflow.com/a/22308927/2836621

Comment: I see @cgohlke has an alpha version of `imagecodecs` that supports JPEG-XR so that might be a good option for you - you may need to install it with `pip install imagecodecs` I have added it into my answer above. Maybe Christoph would care to comment?